# Replacing numeric values in a cloumn by their ranking respective the other values in the column

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say I have A table a that looks like this:

```
+---+--------------+------+
|NUM|     NAME     |POINTS|
+-------------------------+
| 1 |   Peter      | 92   |
| 1 |   Rose       | 93   |
| 1 |   Karl       | 94   |
| 2 |   Frank      | 15   |
| 2 |   Sarah      | 16   | 
+-------------------------+
```

With the primary key being combination of NUM and NAME.

Now I would like to replace the numbers in POINTS with their ranking, starting by 1 for every num. I want to actually update the table.

Example:

```
+---+--------------+------+
|NUM|     NAME     |POINTS|
+-------------------------+
| 1 |   Peter      | 3    |
| 1 |   Rose       | 2    |
| 1 |   Karl       | 1    |
| 2 |   Frank      | 1    |
| 2 |   Sarah      | 2    | 
+-------------------------+
```

What would be the best way of doing that?

Comment: It depends how do you treat equal values. You should use `row_number`, `rank` or `dense_rank`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to actually change the values in the table, you can use a MERGE statement:

```
merge into the_table t
using (
  select num, name, 
         dense_rank() over (partition by num order by points) as rnk
  from the_table
) x on (x.num = t.num and x.name = t.name)
when matched then update
   set points = x.rnk;
```

---

If you just want to *display* the values, use the inner select on its own:

```
select num, name, 
       dense_rank() over (partition by num order by points) as points,
from the_table
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a column to the table for ranking, then loop through the table while there exists a row with no ranking.

Then find the max points where ranking is null, and update ranking for all rows who have those points to their ranking.

The ranking is either a counter if the points are unique, or you could just count the records with ranking every time you loop and have the new ranking be count(records with ranking) + 1

All this would look something like this

```
FOR r in (SELECT * FROM people WHERE ranking IS NULL) LOOP
  SELECT MAX(POINTS)
    INTO temp_points
    FROM people
   WHERE ranking IS NULL;

  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO temp_ranking
    FROM people
   WHERE ranking is not null;

   temp_ranking := temp_ranking + 1;

  UPDATE people
     SET ranking = temp_ranking
    WHERE points = temp_points;
END LOOP;
```